# ¿Existe algun otro codigo para hacer esta aplicacion?

Tags: java, array, combobox, array-bidimensional

Crear aplicación que permita el llenado de un arreglo bidimensional, su posterior consulta y evaluación derivado de un menú tipo combobox generado con JOptionPane, la aplicación debe seguir la siguiente ejecución: lazar una ventana en la cuál se soliciten las marcas y modelos correspondientes a cada arreglo, posteriormente se debe consultar las marcas y seleccionar cuál de ellas desea ver el usuario y una vez seleccionada debe visualizar los modelos de dicha marca, una vez consultado la aplicación debe enviar una ventana preguntando si se desea consultar de nuevo o salir del programa, en caso de optar por consultar de nuevo nos debe presentar de nuevo el combobox y repetir el proceso, en caso de seleccionar cancelar, solo se sale del programa.

Yo lo hice de la siguiente manera, pero creo que hay una forma mas eficiente de hacerla, me gustaria saber

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author coco_
 */
public class Bidimecional_practica3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
 public static void main(String[] args) { 

 //declaracion de arreglos bidimensional
      String[][] marcasYautos = new String[3][5];
//Arreglo para presentar las marcas
  Object[]marcas = new Object[3]; 
  Object opcion_marca;
  
  int a;
  
    
  //Llenado de datos 
 for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
 String marca = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "agregue una marca de autos");
 marcasYautos[i][0] = marca;
 
 for(int x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
     String modelo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "agregue el nombre o modelo del auto"); 
     marcasYautos[i][x] = modelo;
 }
 }
 
 //Consulta de valores al arreglo
 String datos = "";
 String modelo0= "";
 String modelo1= "";       
 String modelo2= "";   

for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
marcas[i]= marcasYautos[i][0];     
    for(int x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
        
    } 
     
}
 for(int x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
    
    modelo0 += "modelo: " + marcasYautos[0][x] + "\n"; 
    modelo1 += "modelo: " + marcasYautos[1][x] + "\n";
    modelo2 += "modelo: " + marcasYautos[2][x] + "\n";
 }
  
  //Construccion de combobox desde JOptionPane
    do{ 
        opcion_marca = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Selecciona una marca", "Marcas",
             JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, marcas, marcas[0]);
     
        if(opcion_marca.equals(marcas[0])){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La marca que eligio es: " + opcion_marca + "\n" + "Los modelos de esa marca son: " + "\n" + modelo0 );
 }else if(opcion_marca.equals(marcas[1])){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La marca que eligio es: " + opcion_marca + "\n" + "Los modelos de esa marca son: " + "\n" + modelo1 );
 }else if(opcion_marca.equals(marcas[2])){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La marca que eligio es: " + opcion_marca + "\n" + "Los modelos de esa marca son: " + "\n" + modelo2 );
     }
     
 
 a= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null," ¿Buscar otra marca existente? " );
        }while(a!= 1);
}
 
 }
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Podrías Utilizar las librerías de Java Swing para poder crear objetos para realizar las acciones que deseas.
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-swing

Comment: **Es super  importante revises [answer] para realizar respuestas en el sitio**, trata de obtener reputación para realizar comentarios, saludos.